# AS3 how to get access to a inruntime created element by his id?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml

so i have a simple application that has a hgroup and i add an element to it. but when i use this.newobject.Somthings i cant get acces to the object.

in my mxml relevant code i have:

```
<s:Hgroup id="headder1" height="25"/>
```

and in my "form creation complete i have":

```
var a:Button = new Button;
a.id='button1';
a.label = 'hello';
headder1.addElement(a);
```

so when i try in any other piece of code to do something like this:

```
var e:String;
e=this.button1.label
```

i get an error. causes there is no button1 accesible. even if i debug the code there is no button1 under this.... and not under headder1....
so i dont know how to work trought this.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the other pieces of code you must point to a.label because you've created:

```
var a:Button = new Button;
```

So you must refer on that.

You try to refer by name of your component with:

```
headder1.getChildByName(NAME OF YOUR BUTTON)
```

but you put

```
a.name = NAME OF YOUR BUTTON
```

Tell me if it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is not a property of `UIComponent` in the classic sense. It **cannot** be set in ActionScript. When you set the ID in MXML, it uses that ID to create a public variable within the generated AS3 class at compile-time, long before it actually runs. MXML doesn't actually run at runtime. Instead, the compiler uses the MXML to generate an ActionScript class at compile-time and *that* is run at runtime.

If I remember correctly, if you do get the object in a different matter and check its `id`, it is not what you set it to.

So you need to save a reference to your button in AS3, or set its name, loop through its parent, and get the object that way.

So do this instead:

```
private var button1:Button;
private function formCreationComplete(e:Event ):void {
    this.button1 = new Button;
    this.button1.id='button1';
    this.button1.label = 'hello';
    headder1.addElement( this.button1 );
}
```

And then later on, you can do this:

```
var e:String;
e = this.button1.label;
```